# Inserting a Download Link in the Quick Edit Actions of the Media Library?

Tags: media-library

What's the best way of doing this:

On The 'Media Library' page, I would like a link next to 'View' (the 'View' that appears when you hover over a Media item) for 'Download'. The 'Download' hyperlink would link directly to the file, unlike the 'View' link which links to a template-based page with either the embedded image or a link to the non-image file.

I have a lot of PDF's in my media library that I look up regularly, having to click on 'View' and then click on the hyper-linked file name just to get to the file is a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified version of a piece of code found in [this tutorial](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-quick-edit-menu).

```
add_filter('media_row_actions', 'wpse_30159_qe_download_link', 10, 2);

function wpse_30159_qe_download_link($actions, $post) {
    /* Almost sure this is not necessary. Just in case... */
    global $current_screen;
    if ( 'upload' != $current_screen->id ) 
        return $actions; 

    // if not PDF file, return default $actions
    if ( 'application/pdf' != $post->post_mime_type )
        return $actions;

    // relative path/name of the file
    $the_file = str_replace(WP_CONTENT_URL, '.', $post->guid);

    // adding the Action to the Quick Edit row
    $actions['Download'] = '<a href="'.WP_CONTENT_URL.'/download.php?file='.$the_file.'">Download</a>';

    return $actions;    
}
```

The download script resides here: `/wp-content/download.php`.
And [here's](https://gist.github.com/2863355) a sample code of a *force download* script.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 being used it is easier:

```
//medianattachemeny https://trepmal.com/filter_hook/media_row_actions/
add_filter ('media_row_actions','add_direct_link', 10, 3 );
function add_direct_link( $actions, $post, $detached ) {
    $actions['file_url'] = '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) . '" download="' . wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) . '" target="_blank">Actual File</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```