# Remove Posts Quick Edit link for specific user role? WP 3.3

Tags: posts, user-roles, permissions, quick-edit

I am using Wordpress 3.3.2 with the following plugin:
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

The plugin works perfectly but the author said there is currently no way to achieve this from the plugin, So I am wondering if there is either another plugin or any code modifications I can make to achieve them.

1. I created a custom user role Called "Member"
2. I applied certain permissions so the user can only sees options to make posts in the backend.
3. When making a post, the user does not see the option to edit the post "slug", enable comments, apply password to post, or to make the post private.
4. The problem comes when viewing the posts lists via the backend admin, the user has the option to "Quick Edit" which allows them to change the "slug", apply password, make post private, and choose the checkbox to "allow comments".

When Viewing the lists of posts from the backend, I only want the user to be able to see the "Edit" and "View" link that appears when you hover over a post. I do not want the "Quick Edit" link to appear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based [on this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54080/12615), yours was easy:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions',     'wpse_49800_qe_download_link', 10, 2);
add_filter('page_row_actions',     'wpse_49800_qe_download_link', 10, 2);

// for Custom Post Types
// add_filter('cpt_name_row_actions', 'wpse_49800_qe_download_link', 10, 2);

function wpse_49800_qe_download_link($actions, $post) {
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js'],$actions['trash']);
    return $actions; 
}
```

Notice that you don't mention the `'Trash'`, so it's being removed as well.

---

#### Plugin of interest

[Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) is able to hide ***lots of stuff*** from the Admin panel based on user roles.